# Visual Basic 2010 Inserting current date to database

Tags: visual-studio-2010, datetime

I can't seem to add the current time to my database. I've tried the following:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
        dataFile = "F:\daniel\Sample Program\database\attendance.accdb"
        connString = provider & dataFile
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        myConnection.Open()

    Dim Timein As Date
    Timein = Now()
    Timein = "insert into timesheet (time1) values (NOW())"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(Timein, myConnection)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("time1", CType(Button1.Text, Date)))

    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        myConnection.Close()



    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim Timein As Date
Timein = Now()
Dim sqlText as String
sqlText = "insert into timesheet (time1) values (timeParam)"
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlText, myConnection)
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("timeParam", Timein))
```

Disclaimer:  this was done from memory and not tested.

Edited to add:  how to insert two values at once:

```
 Dim sqlText as String
 sqlText = "insert into timesheet (time1, time2) values(timeParam1, timeParam2)"
 Dim cmd as OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlText, myConnection)
 cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("timeParam1", Timein))
 cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("timeParam2", Timeout))
```

If what you need to do is come back later and update your first timesheet row with a second value, that will require an `Update` statement.  Post another question asking about that.

To modify how the timesheet value is displayed, you can use the `String.Format()` function:

```
  txtTime1.Text = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}", Timein)
```

That long string used as the first parameter is what's called a `custom format string`:  you can read about them at [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you it worked! 

2015-09-20 00:31:28.746353100

how can i remove the 746353100? how can i edit what format of date i want to be inputted?

Comment: 1 more question, i used a time in and time out function in my program my problem is that they are not both in the same row how can i make them in appear in the same row?

Comment: @D.delacruz  With regard to the date format:  are you talking about controlling what users can enter, or displaying the values that they have entered?  Also, when you say the time in and time out are not in the same row, are you referring to rows in the database?

Comment: displaying the values that they have entered, if i click the button it should display the current hours and date in my database, yes im referring to my database

Comment: @D.delacruz  OK, for the database it may be as simple as needing to insert both values in the same `insert` statement.  I have changed my answer to include this.

Comment: @D.delacruz  I have also included information about formatting dates for display.

Answer (score 0):

- if u want **current date and Time** (example:27/12/2019 12:00 )

sql="INSERT INTO TableName (id, date) VALUES(" 1 ",'" NOW "',");"

- if u want **current date only** (example:27/12/2019 )

sql="INSERT INTO TableName (id, date) VALUES(" 1 ",'" TODAY "',");"